# Start new Activity using button click

Tags: android, button

I have been trying to start a new activity using a button but my application crashes

The code i use :

```
Button b = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
    }
});
```

But my app still crashes........

Comment: Have you added Activity2 into your manifest.xml? or upload your logcat.

Comment: So, how does it crash (log, please)?

Comment: what exception you are getting post logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may because you did not declare Activity2 in AndroidManifest.xml

Please make sure you have something like this in you manifest file

```
   <activity android:name=".Activity2" />
```

Comment: This is a guess, not a proper answer.

Comment: actually you are right....

Answer (score 0):

You can move to desired activity on button click.

**xml:**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />
```

In your main activity just add this method:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Yeah and most important thing dont forget to define you activity in manifest.xml

```
 <activity
      android:name=".Activity2"
      android:label="@string/app_name">          
 </activity>
```